# Rails routes: Wrong singular for resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have the following line in my `routes.rb` (Rails 4.1.4):

```
resources :request_caches
```

However, when I run `rake routes` I get the following output:

```
request_caches    GET    /request_caches(.:format)            request_caches#index
                  POST   /request_caches(.:format)            request_caches#create
new_request_cach  GET    /request_caches/new(.:format)        request_caches#new
edit_request_cach GET    /request_caches/:id/edit(.:format)   request_caches#edit
request_cach      GET    /request_caches/:id(.:format)        request_caches#show
                  PATCH  /request_caches/:id(.:format)        request_caches#update
                  PUT    /request_caches/:id(.:format)        request_caches#update
                  DELETE /request_caches/:id(.:format)        request_caches#destroy
```

As you can see, Rails somehow maps `request_caches` plural to `request_cach` singular. But it should be `request_cache`. Is this some kind of special case, because of the word `caches`? I've also played around with

```
resources :request_caches, as: :request_cache
```

But this results in wrong routes like `request_cache_index`. And furthermore, I think this is a standard task and should be solved clearly using Rails intern route helpers.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what if you do this `resources :request_caches, :path => "request_cache"` i think it will work

Comment: I don't know the reason for it but you can achieve it with putting `inflect.irregular 'request_cache', 'request_caches'` in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

Comment: If you don't worry about why it is generating `request_cach` and just looking for a solution, then I can post my comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rails guesses.  It's not perfect.  In `config/initializers/inflections.rb` add

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
   inflect.irregular 'request_cache', 'request_caches'  
end
```

You'll need to restart the server as it's in an initializer.

Comment: thx, I've accepted your answer, first come, first serve ;) but thanks to the others as well!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `config/initializers/inflections.rb`. There should be some examples in the comments.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.singular 'request_caches' 'request_cache'
end
```

Be sure to restart the server after making changes to an initializer.

Comment: The :de here might be problematic - should be :en?

Comment: Right. Copy & paste mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As I said,you can achieve it by changing `config/initializers/inflections.rb` like below

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'request_cache', 'request_caches'
end
```